# dynamic objects in if condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to make if condition which contains dynamic object? i tried this way, but error

```
function pass(xxx:String,yyy:String,zzz:String)
{
    //trace(xxx,yyy,zzz);
    if (this[xxx].hitTestObject(this[yyy])) //an original if (obj1.hitTestObject(obj2))
    {
       trace("right");
    }
    else
    {
      trace("fail");
    }
}
```

"this[]" is not work, TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
"this[]" can work if it is outside "if". 
Is there any other way for this problem? Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getChildByName()`, if you are transferring names of the MCs, but check if that name is a direct child of `this`.

```
function pass(xxx:String,yyy:String,zzz:String):void {
    var x=this.getChildByName(xxx);
    if (!x) return;
    var y=this.getChildByName(yyy);
    if (!y) return; // insert similar for zzz here
    if (x.hitTestObject(y))     {
        trace("right");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("fail");
    }
}
```

Otherwise specify what inputs does thje function have.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to be supplying the object names as Strings, I suggest changing the argument types to `DisplayObject`:

```
function pass(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):void
{
    if(a.hitTestObject(b))
    {
        trace("right");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("fail");
    }
}
```

If you need to use the Strings, just do this:

```
var obj1:DisplayObject = getChildByName("obj1");
var obj2:DisplayObject= getChildByName("obj2");

pass(obj1, obj2);
```